# Short story about artists in the future

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

In the future artistic people have all the freedom, only geniuses are born and took control.

The story takes time after a while, everything is in disarray, buildings don't make sense at all.

Then the story focuses on a grandpa and a grandson, being in their living room with the grandpa asking his grandson to not burn the carpet with a looking glass, to which the grandson replies that the symphony of feelings released by the burning of the carpet is art as well.

Comment: You could improve this question by going through the checklists [here](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question) and editing in any relevant info you can think to add.